Swagger UI keeps shows Swagger Petstore
I used this dependency to configure my Swagger UI:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

It was working fine till I added the Spring Security for authorization of APIs.
Now when I try to access the Swagger UI url, http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, it keeps showing me a Swagger Petstore page for some reason.
Any idea why this is happening?
Here's my SecurityConfig.java
package com.example.employeemanager.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        UserDetails admin = User.withUsername("Aman").password(encoder.encode("1234")).roles("ADMIN", "USER").build();
        
        UserDetails user = User.withUsername("Andreas").password(encoder.encode("12345678")).roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(admin, user);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("removal")
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/welcome").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-resources/**", "/configuration/ui", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui/index.html").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/user/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/admin/**").authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}

Here's my application.properties
spring.application.name=employeemanager
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

